# How to iterate over a FormData entries() array without using for-loop

Tags: javascript, iteration, eslint

I try to iterate over a FormData entries() object.
ESlint is giving me error that I really shouldn't do it the way I have done below: 
`iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.`

```js
for (const row of data.entries()) {
  const search = row[0].replace('internal_', '');

  if (search.length > 0 && search.substr(1, 3) !== 'ext') {
    currentCTX.data[search][2] = row[1];
  }
  const currentData = JSON.stringify(currentCTX.data);
  const { feedId } = window;
  const params = { userSave: currentData, id: parseInt(feedId, 10), channel: 'import' };
  const res = fetchData(`${apiUrl}mapping`, params).then(() => window.location = '/');
}
```

However `entries()` doesn't have forEach() so I can not use it.

What is a clean way to do the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `for..of`, spread the `.entries()` iterator into an array so you can use `forEach` on it:

```
[...data.entries()].forEach((row) => {
  // ...
```